# Lifting a Mass with one or multiple motors

Tags: torque

I’m working on a DIY project and need some assistance. I have a single motor that can lift a load of 500 pounds.

Is it possible to use 4 smaller motors to lift the same load as long as the 4 smaller motors equal the same torque as the single motor?

This isn’t a question about gearing or placing the 4 motors on a single shaft....each of the smaller motors would work independently to lift the load.

My thought is this... You have a 3’ lever on a fulcrum situated at a given distance (let’s say the fulcrum is exactly in the center of the 3’ lever. 100 foot pounds is placed on the lever, but the load does not lift. Is it possible to place another lever against the load with the exact same conditions as the 1st lever. Then, both levers are given 100 foot pounds....will the load lift with the added mechanism.

This is hypothetical of course.... I would love to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring losses, the total force on the object is all that matters.  So 4 motors each supplying 25% of the torque would be exactly equivalent to 1 motor at 100% torque.

This applies everywhere.  Two people each exerting 50 pounds can lift a 100 pound object;  two levers double the force applied; two locomotives double the pulling power, etc.

Comment: In theory... In practice by using one motor it is way way easier to build.

Comment: Scott....this is exactly what I thought as well as your analogy.